# what is the right approach to combine CompletableFuture and JdbcTamplate?

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-jdbc, completable-future

I am trying to make some simple queries to the database using JdbcTemplate. Will my approach be right?

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<ResultClass1> query1() {
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(jdbcTemplate.query("my sql",rowMap, paramter));  
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<ResultClass2> query2() {
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(jdbcTemplate.query("my sql2",rowMap, paramter));  
}

CompletableFuture<List<ResultClass1> future1 = dao1.query1();
CompletableFuture<List<ResultClass2> future2 = dao2.query2();

CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it, if what you're trying to do is run those queries simultaneously and wait for both to finish. However, your application is blocked until both finish. To avoid this, typically you do something like this:

```
CompletionStage<CombinedResult> combinedResult =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).thenApplyAsync(dummy -> {
  List<ResultClass1> query1Results = future1.join();
  List<ResultClass2> query2Results = future2.join();
  // more code...
  return someCombinedResult;
});
```

This allows you to continue writing code around a hypothetical combined result, all the way up your call stack, so that you can even return to your main process's event loop, which frees your process to do other things until your queries complete.